# Read file in python - Last line "None"

Tags: python

I make a code to read each line of the file "name":

```
  def readFile(name):
    with open(name) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip() 
            print line
```

My file have this:

```
 11001
 10010
```

My output is:

```
 11001
 10010
 None
```

Why None?

Comment: `f = int('0b'+f.readline(), 2)` Python binary values begin with '0b'

Comment: @DhruvSomani no, that's just the literal notation. Thomas has it right -- `int("11001", 2)` is valid. `int("11001/n", 2)` is not.

Comment: @AdamSmith, Yes, that is invalid but `int("11001\n",2`)` is valid (check your slash).  Leading and trailing whitespace is OK for `int()`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen you have any solution for the "None" ?

Comment: `int()` doesn't return None.  You have another problem with your code.  Edit the question to show a reproducible example.

Comment: @MarkTolonen done, I think it's explicit now.

Comment: If I were to put that code in a file and run it, it would print nothing, because all it does is define a function.  How are you calling the function?  I'm going to guess it is something like `print readFile(...)`.  The function has no return value, so printing it would return `None`.

Comment: no i'm calling readFile(name) only, because i print the line inside the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, here's a neat trick.

```
  def readFile(name):
    with open(name) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip() 
            print line
```

Comment: @PRVS Is the last line in your file empty?

Comment: @PRVS I don't know mate I just tried it and it worked me, if your trying it in idle try it in the terminal.

Comment: I'm calling wrong the function, solved it. thanks . :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to check that there is no '\r' or '\n' in the result of `readline()`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're not properly stripping your line. There shouldn't really be a need to call `readline` however.

```
numbers = []

with open('path/to/your/file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()  # important!
        num = int(line, 2)
        numbers.append(num)
```

If you just want to get only those lines that correctly convert to binary (and there are more lines that won't):

```
...
    line = line.strip()
    try:
        num = int(line, 2)
    except ValueError:
        # line isn't a valid integer in binary
        pass  # but that's okay
    else:
        # if it is, let's....
        numbers.append(num)
```

Comment: Instead of use numbers.append(num) I use print num, and I got None too.

Comment: @PRVS well `int` can never give a `None`, so I'm not sure what it is you're doing. You haven't posted enough code.

Comment: Now i'm making this:
`with open(name) as f:
  for line in f:
   line = line.strip()
   num = int(line, 2)
   print num`

And the last line is None.

The file have one number like this 101010 in each line.

Comment: @PRVS no it's not. You can't get a `None` out of an `int`. Something else is causing this. Maybe you're returning `None` from the function and your REPL is printing back the return value? that would be silly, but it's ***definitely*** not a call to `int` that's giving `None`. Try just doing `for line in f: line = line.strip(); print line`

Comment: With this it prints too "None"

Comment: I delete the "\n" of the end of the file, but not works.

Comment: `int('\r\n101010\r\n',2)` works.  `int()` strips whitespace implicitly.

Comment: @PRVS, just print the string that you are converting so you can see what is invalid about it.

Comment: I put only this: `with open(name) as f:
  for line in f:
   line = line.strip() 
   print line`but gives me the "None"

Comment: @PRVS, `line.strip()` doesn't return None either.  Make a small script that reproduces the problem and post the *exact* code and the *exact* (cut-n-paste) output.  Edit your question so it shows the exact script and exact formatting.

Comment: My guess is that he's running this in a REPL and it's outputting the return value of the function (which is `None`).